# how to make a list using while with input function

Tags: python-3.x

How to collect a list of user inputs using the `While` loop?

I tried using an if statement to stop inputs when the input is 'quit' but it doesn't print after the input, it either prints 1 input and with some tweaking it goes on appending the same input over and over.

```
#input methods with lists
x=input('Type to fill your list here:')
list=[]
while x.lower()!='quit':
  print()
  if x.lower()!='quit':
    list.append(x)
    print(list)
```

I need to print the list after every input appended with the previous results too but the actual output is either it stops after 1 input or it appends the same input over and over again.

PS: I'm trying it with strings and not int

Comment: You only ever ask the user for input once.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix a while loop that goes on forever in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58343621/how-to-fix-a-while-loop-that-goes-on-forever-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Your input method needs to be in the loop too, otherwise what basically is happening is that it asks for the user input just once and then moves on to the while loop.

Here you go:

```
list = []
while True:
    x=input('Type to fill your list here: ')
    if x.lower()!='quit':
        list.append(x)
        print(list)
    else:
        print(list)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Kalyan the input function should be included in the while loop.
Your code when corrected would look like this.

```
list=[]
while True:
    x=input('Type to fill your list here:')
    if x.lower() == "quit":
        print(list)
        break
    list.append(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, that worked using a break after the if and moving the if logic to else
Here's the sample code

```
list=[]
while True:
 x=input('Type to fill your list here:')
 if x.lower()=='quit':
  break
 else:
  list.append(x)
  print(list)
```

Comment: You should just upvote all the correct answers and accept one of them

Comment: @Trollsors - Not quite correct, you should upvote answers you found useful, if additional answers didn't add anything new then there's no need to upvote them

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try` for End of file exception.

```
list_ = []
while 1:
    try:
        string = input()
        list_.append(string)
        print(list_)
    except EOFError:
        break
```

input string is appended to list `list_`. But I think it will work if input is taken through a file